# Regex to extract an IP address from a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to retrieve the IP address from a string. I'm definitely not the first to ask this question, but I couldn't really find an answer doing exactly what we need.

If there is somewhere in the string a combination of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, regardless of the text around it, it should extract this number with the dots in between. So it can be used with `Test-Connection`.

I'm not trying to determin if an IP Address is valid, but I am trying to retrieve the IP Address from a string. Even if it is invalid, like say 900.999.800.254.

**Example:**

```
Input             Expected result
-----             ---------------
IP_10.57.50.91    10.57.50.91
10.57.50.73       10.57.50.73
10.58.4.37 IP     10.58.4.37
ip 10.63.1.22     10.63.1.22
BELPRLIXH300      $False
ip 10.63          $False
```

I've tried so far the the regex's suggested [here](https://chrisjwarwick.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/more-regular-expressions-regex-for-ip-v4-addresses/) but they don't give us the IP address as output in the variable `$Matches`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but if I try `'IP_10.10.22.45' -match "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"` it doesn't work and gives me `$False` instead of the number.

Comment: I successfully testet every IP address with the ExtractValidIpAddress function from you link.

Comment: Yes, it does give `$True` or `$False`, but it doesn't extract the number to be used with `Test-Connection`.

Comment: remove the anchors... ^,$

Comment: If I try this `'IP_10.10.22.45' -match "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"` it doesn't give the correct output, not even in `$Matches`.

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/rS5mE7/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ips = @('IP_10.57.50.91',
    '10.57.50.73',
    '10.58.4.37 IP',
    'ip 10.63.1.22',
    'BELPRLIXH300',
    'ip 10.63'
)

$regex = [regex] "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"

$regex.Matches($ips) | %{ $_.value }
```

Comment: Only problem is that this one isn't matchin `IP_10.57.50.91`. It should also put out the number `10.57.50.91`.

Comment: remove the first \b in the regex (word boundary)